# BizTalk 2020 SFTP producing errors relating to WinSCP

Tags: sftp, biztalk, winscp, biztalk-2020

Appreciate any info or pointers that anybody might have.

I am running BizTalk 2020, attempting to set up my first SFTP send port to send a flat file to an SFTP server, using username & password authentication.

When the port is active and a file is placed in the relevant receive location, BizTalk attempts to send the file but produces an error that relates it seems to WinSCP:

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "*XYZ*" with URL "*XYZ*%MessageID%.csv". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void WinSCP.SessionOptions.set_SshHostKeyPolicy(WinSCP.SshHostKeyPolicy)'.

WinSCP version installed is v15.9.6.

Any ideas as to what would produce this error? How would I set an Ssh host key policy?

Comment: So what's your adapter configuration? What made BizTalk try to call `set_SshHostKeyPolicy`? Actually WinSCP 15.9.6 does have `set_SshHostKeyPolicy`, so it looks like BizTalk is calling an older version of WinSCP somehow.

Comment: Hi Martin - not sure about the adaptor configuration. The call was made when an outgoing file was placed into a receive location connected with the send port. I'll check the versions - thanks for the pointer. Jon

Comment: Which BizTalk Cumulative Update have you got installed?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hello - not yet, We are awaiting some external help to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved - in the send port, accept any ssh server host key = no, then entered the MD5 format host key fingerprint of the destination server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Don't forget to use the green tick to mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

The version of WinSCP used by BizTalk 2020 depends on the [Cumulative Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/service-pack-and-cumulative-update-list-for-biztalk-server-108e5e94-4558-8b57-d5fb-45984506d56f) you have installed.

- CU 1 = v5.17.6
- CU 2 = v5.17.6
- CU 3 = v5.19.2

None of them use v15.9.6, although you could try a assembly re-direct to force it to use that version, but you will have to do some testing to ensure that doesn't introduce any issues.

In earlier version of BizTalk you had to manually upgrade the WinSCP DLL in the BizTalk runtime folder as per [BizTalk 2016 CU5 gotcha: upgrade WinSCP to v5.13.1](https://pvandenheede.wordpress.com/2019/02/14/biztalk-2016-cu5-gotcha-upgrade-winscp-to-v5-13-1/), it is unclear from the CU documentation for BizTalk 2020 if it requires the same steps.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain how BizTalk works with the WinSCP .NET Assembly. Does it come with its own copy? Or does it rely on an installed version of WinSCP?

Comment: So possibly OP updated to CU3 that needs 5.19.2, but OP still has 5.17.6, which indeed does not have `set_SshHostKeyPolicy`. The version OP claims to have (15.9.6) might be the standalone WinSCP installation (`C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP`), not the DLL copy from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server XXXX`.

Comment: Hi Folks - thanks for the info/thoughts. I'll take a look in the morning. WinSCP was installed by a consultant, will take a look to understand if it's the standalone one.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  If you want to address BiztalkDev you have to either do it on their question, or use the ATname like I just did with you.